# Why in this Blender file cant I add a texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

Relative noob here.
Having trouble adding texture to an object. Added material, then set colour field to Image Texture and selected the texture to us, but nothing appears on the object. it works fine in other files Ihave, but I created this from fresh recently and don't understand what is different and why it's not working. Have tried different textures that work elsewhere but nothing seems to work for me.
Using Blender 2.78 with cycles render.

My Blender file is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0DWfIMJ2SXoUm1fZ0Z0d254M00)

Will be grateful for help. TIA.

Comment: You should unwrap your mesh, unless texture will not be applied.

Comment: OK I was completely ignorant of UV mapping but following your hint I watched [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F_x6G9Yqdlg) and can now map texture to my object. But still not clear why I was having a problem with the file referenced but not with another I'm using. Nonetheless; many thanks.

Comment: Probably the other files had already unwrapped meshes.

Comment: Not convinced, as I created those myself also. I dont recall doing any UV stuff as I didnt know anything about it.